# Is multi-node Sagemaker training batched per-node or shared?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Tensorflow, and am noticing that individual steps are slower with multiple nodes than with one, so I am a bit confused as to what constitutes a step on multiple training nodes on Sagemaker.

If my batch size is 10 and I have 5 training nodes, is a "step" 2 from each node or 10 from each node?

What if I have a batch size of 1 and 5 nodes?

Note - a 'node' here is an individual training instance, count created from `train_instance_count=5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this notebook for an example of distributed training with TF: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_distributed_mnist/tensorflow_distributed_mnist.ipynb

"Each instance will predict a batch of the dataset, calculate loss and minimize the optimizer. One entire loop of this process is called training step.

A global step is a global variable shared between the instances. It's necessary for distributed training, so the optimizer will keep track of the number of training steps between runs:

train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
That is the only required change for distributed training!"